# PHP Extract header row from CSV file - code explanation

Tags: php, csv

I am following a tutorial and have come across code that I need explaining.

This template php code is for parsing a csv file and populating the $data associative array with the results.

```
<?php

 $header = false;
 $data = [];
 $file = fopen($filename, 'r');
 while(!feof($file)) {
   $row = fgetcsv($file, 0, ',');
   if($row == [NULL] || $row === FALSE) { continue; }
   if(!$header) {
     $header = $row;
   } else {
     $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
   }
 }
 fclose($file);
```

From this example csv file:

```
brand,model,year,category,gender,color,weight_kg,condition_id,price
Trek,Emonda,2017,Hybrid,Unisex,black,1.5,5,1495.00
Cannondale,Synapse,2016,Road,Unisex,matte black,1.0,5,1999.00
Schwinn,Cutter,2016,City,Unisex,white,18,4,450.00
Mongoose,Switchback Sport,2015,Mountain,Mens,blue,24,2,399.00
Diamondback,Overdrive,2016,Mountain,Unisex,dark green,23.7,3,565.00
Schwinn,21-Speed Suburban CS,2015,Hybrid,Womens,burgundy,20,3,299.00
Schwinn,Sanctuary 7-Speed,2016,Cruiser,Womens,purple,19.5,3,190.00
Vilano,Forza,2015,Road,Unisex,silver,13.6,4,390.00
SE,Creature,2016,BMX,Mens,dark grey,9.1,2,410.00
```

I understand everything except this section:

```
if(!$header) {
 $header = $row;
}
```

I'm struggling to understand how the php code is recognizing which is the header row and which is not.
Could someone please explain, thank you.

Comment: `$header = false;` initially. First row is incoming, `$header` is false, so `$header` will be set to `$row`. On the next iteration `$header` will no longer be false so `continue`

Comment: Its simply the first row. On the first iteration of the loop the variable $header is not set(!$header), so your script sets it ($header=$row). On the second iteration $header is set, so everything else is added to $data[]. Thats about it. Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line of your CSV file is the header.
To make sure this header is not read as a normal line he uses "$header = false;" at the beginning.

After the first iteration he updates the value:

```
if(!$header) {
    $header = $row;
}
```

The value of $row is filled, so essentialy true